# how to get path of linked categories in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical

i have a table of categories as follows:

```
c_id | c_ref | c_title
----------------------
1    | 0     | cat
----------------------
2    | 0     | cat
----------------------
3    | 0     | cat
----------------------
4    | 2     | sub
----------------------
5    | 4     | sub
----------------------
6    | 2     | sub
----------------------
7    | 3     | sub
```

i wanna get results like this:
for example results of selecting c_id=2 should be:

```
c_id | c_ref | c_title
----------------------
2    | 0     | cat
----------------------
4    | 2     | sub
----------------------
5    | 4     | sub
----------------------
6    | 2     | sub
```

i've just wrote this query:

```
SELECT node.c_id , node.c_ref , parent.c_id , parent.c_ref

FROM `categories` as node , `categories` as parent

WHERE node.c_ref = parent.c_id or (node.c_ref = 0)
```

but i have no idea how to get a single path

Comment: You need recursive select :) there are a lot of threads about it just like what you need..

Comment: @Svetlio thanks a lot i found the solution